# number of ways of expressing a number as sum of 5 squares modulo 10

Tags: number-theory

Look at the function $r_5(n)$, which is defined by the number of ordered integers $(a,b,c,d,e)$ which satisfy $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2= n$. Now, I have conjectured that the unit's digit of $r_5(n)$ is 2 when $n$ is of the form $5p^2$, and its unit's digit is 0 when $n$ is not of that form. Is there any proof for my conjecture?

I have checked this for very large values of $p$ (upto $p= 100$). But can this be proved?

Comment: For what it's worth, these numbers are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A038671 (but for positive $a,\dots,e$).

Comment: I wouldn't call $p=100$ very large :)

Comment: Requesting to close this for a week, as this is a [Brilliant problem](https://brilliant.org/i/mhXTxV/).

Comment: @CalvinLin I've deleted my answer. Wondering, how does Stack Exchange support closing a question for a period - is it something that needs to be re-opened explicitly, or is that a SE mechanism for temporary closures?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks. I'm not too sure what their procedure is. Currently, I flag the question and a moderator closes or deletes it. I would favorite the question, so that I can flag it for reopening in a week.

Comment: Though, more often nowadays, the questions stays open and people do hide (delete) their posts for a while. I've also not seen that many questions posted on MSE. I know that there are other users who flag Brilliant problems, but there is no standardized approach that MSE has. There have been a few discussions on Meta, but it hasn't gone far as yet.

Comment: I cannot comment, so I am writing this here. @Calvin Lin:- You don't need to worry about that, I have already used my 3 tries. But then I turned to WolframAlpha and found a pattern. It seems to give the correct answer (I entered it in my own shared link). As you can see, I have tested values of p from 1 to 100, but to get the correct answer I had to check it till 33 only. I am very interested in the solution, and simply can't wait till next week. Anyways, please remove your shared link, because if someone tries to cheat he can log out from his account and get 3 extra tries. I would remove the

Comment: The problem is, this gives other people information to answer the question, too. Whether you have exhausted your chances or not, it still potentially spoils the question for other people.

Comment: And no, for all solutions, it is not merely twice the positive solutions. It is way more complicated than that.